# how to create android re sizable split pane ( to display two fragments )?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I want to create an android split pane which has a draggable vertical bar to resize both layouts on each side, what I thought to do is, change the weight of layouts dynamically with onTouch Listener, if anyone can suggest another method or a suitable library for this purpose. it'll be a huge help.

Comment: this link will help you [link] (https://www.techjini.com/blog/multi-window-split-screen-android/)

Answer (score 1):

you can use this third party library 
https://github.com/MobiDevelop/android-split-pane-layout

Comment: This library doesn't seem to be maintained.